# WKWebView: Add a button that loads up URL

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

On my WKWebView app, I want to add a button that user can click to go to the home URL.

I have the home URL stored in `url`:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!
```

Then I create the button like this:

```
let htmlURL = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Home",style: .Done,target: webView,action: #selector(webView!.goBack))

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = htmlURL
```

Obviously, I need to change the `webView!.goBack` part. My question is, what do I change it to so that when the user clicks the `htmlURL` button, it goes to the `url`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add an action/function, `loadHome()` for example, to the view controller and use `webView.loadRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest)` to load the passed `NSURLRequest`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/loadRequest:

```
let htmlURL = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Home", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(loadHome))

func loadHome() {
    webView.loadRequest(homeUrlRequest)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this?: `let htmlURL = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Home",style: .Done,target: webView,action: #selector(webView.loadRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest))` -- this gave me an error stating that I should add a comma, and when I did so, it still remained as an error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You can add a function to your view controller, like `func viewHome()` then change it to #selector(viewHome).

Comment: In `func viewHome()` you can call `webView.loadRequest`

Comment: Can you please edit your answer demonstrating this with code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You bet! Added it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, although I'm receiving the following error: ´Use of unresolved identifier 'homeUrlRequest'´ -- is there a bug in the code? What are we missing? Thanks again for the effort @narohi

Comment: Figured it out with: `func loadHome() { let url = NSURL(string: "http://domain.com")! webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))}`

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Perfect! Glad you got it running